# Save Theme Primary Color and Theme Brightness, and load on startup Flutter

Tags: flutter, themes, settings

I am using [this code](https://gist.github.com/Roaa94/e270f22c0270a16748ae3193d87b4d82) to switch between light mode and dark mode and choose the primary color.
Works well, but it doesn't save nor load on app restart. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the data anywhere. You can either use [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage), [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), or any other package you want.

You can achieve it by storing the `ThemeMode` in the device, when you're updating the value, then loading it on startup, and when you load you can simply update the Provider's value

Answer (score 0):

You can save user's option in his device using package [localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage).

Init localstorage somewhere (in global state) with

```
final storage = new LocalStorage('my_data.json');
```

in main() func check if your storage ready to work with

```
void main() async {
await storage.ready;
runApp(App());
}
```

Set data with

```
const String themeKey = 'theme'; // or any key you want
await storage.setItem(themeKey , 'light'); // or 'dark' or any value you want
```

You can put that in Provider consturctor:

```
class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
ThemeProvider({this.selectedThemeMode});
  ThemeMode selectedThemeMode;
///....
}
```

And  put in it like that:

```
final savedTheme = storage.getItem(themeKey);
    ThemeMode selectedThemeMode = appThemes[0].mode;

swtich(savedTheme) {
    case 'ligth':
    selectedThemeMode = appThemes[0].mode;
    /// other cases
    }

 

return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(selectedThemeMode: selectedThemeMode),
        ),
// ....
```

and use that value to specify choosed theme.

Comment: Can you please provide an example how to set the theme after I loaded it from Storage?

Comment: in main() func you can init localstorage just before `runApp()`. You should write  `await storage.ready;` where storage if variable for your LocalStorage(). Then you get item and write it to some global variable. And put it in your ThemeProvider as initialValue

Comment: I do not understand the "put in your ThemeProvider as initialValue" Can you please provide some code? Have you ever looked at the link with the code I provided? Thanks!

Comment: I edited answer, check it out. Hope it helps

Comment: It doesn't work. The storage module doesn't have time to load the file so it just returns null. How do I fix it?

Comment: Made one more edit. You shuld check if your localstorage ready (with Future).

Comment: Still it returns null, even if trying to print to console from main function after the async storage.ready

Comment: Did you set selected theme to storage? Try check it right after set

Comment: Yes, I did. Even if I let the code run, it returns null, but after a hot reload, it returns the correct value. So it's something in the initializing code, not the saving.